# How to create and attach softkeyboard in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in android development. I want to make and attach one soft keyboard for android and want to open it on edittext's click. I have gone through with soft keyboard sample given by android sdk but not really able to attach it with android. How can I do this ?
Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install softkeybaord correctly ? if Yes, just go to setting then language & keybaord..
just Check your keybaord ( it wil be "soft keybaord" by standard ) then at editbox hold and choose Imput method, you will see your sample keybaord,choose it .. now u have this keybaord attached to your editbox input.

if this wont solve you issue, please be more spesific on what you need ..

good luck

Comment: Hi Mohammed, now am able to attach it on my device, one more thing can we change the position of softkeyboard means if I am to set keyborad position little bit up from down so can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override draws method in LatinKeyboardView :

```
  @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int offsetup=10;//px
        this.setPadding(0, 0, 0,offsetup);
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getRight(), getBottom()-offsetup);
        super.draw(canvas);         
    }
```

actually here I just shifted it up by padding and cut it by clipRect.
in canvas there are another interesting methods ( rotate, scale, translate , & ...)

[image]

---

This image was taken from Emulator has keybaord with offsetup ( 20 px )

I hope this helps you.

M.